# Idempotency of the product of projections

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

Let $P,Q$ be Hermitian projections (i.e. idempotent). Is there any elegant proof of the fact that $(PQ)^{2} = cPQ$ for some constant $c$?

This question is motivated from the Young symmetrizer $c_{\lambda} = a_{\lambda}b_{\lambda}$. (For reference, Theorem 4.2 of Fulton & Harris.) Considering $\mathbb{C}S_{n}$ as a complex vector space, we can easily check that the right multiplications by $a_{\lambda}$ and $b_{\lambda}$ are Hermitian projections. I think the statement written above holds for general Hermitian projections rather than specific operators $a_{\lambda},b_{\lambda}$, but is's difficult to find an elegant proof of this.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yes, I have tried the projections onto 1-dimensional subspaces lying in a 2-dimensional space. In this case, the proof can be done by direct computation but I'm not sure how to approach when the ambient space is higher dimensional and the projections are onto arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: Do you mean $P,Q$ are the same orthogonal projections onto the line of 45 degrees?